# How to add Specify Trusted Domains for Inline Frames for logout url

Tags: iframe, csp

im doing silent signout, that will load my page `https://<domain>.my.salesforce.com` via iframe

But im getting error related to

```
salesforce because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'"
```

I tried to add Trust Domain follow this document https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_clickjack_specify_iframe_trusted_domains.htm&type=5 for both `Visualforce Pages` and `Surveys`

but it dont work, does everyone meet this and give me some hint to resolve it?